# Using 2 differents bottomTabs on differents screens (multitabs questions) - React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

i've a question, maybe someone can help me, the situation is the next i've a main layout using bottom tabs, my question and actual need is.. when i go inside any tab lets say Tab 2 and i place a button into the main View of it and navigate to other page, i'd like to replace the actual bottom tab layout with a new one, with different icons and that stuff,  i'm not sure how to achieve this, anyone has a any example about this scenario? in addition to this i need to keep the stack navigation so i would like to be able to get back to the old bottom tab layout inside the new bottom tab layout, i really tried many apporaches like using setStackRoot and pushing a new screen with a an object including a bottomTabs declaration's not not working as expected actually my current code is the next:

```
export const navigateMainRootTabPage = () => {
  Promise.all([
    Icon.getImageSource('comments', 24),
    Icon.getImageSource('bell', 24),
    Icon.getImageSource('user', 24)
  ]).then(sources => {
    Navigation.setRoot({
      root: {
        bottomTabs: {
          id: 'mainBottonTab',
          children: [
            {
              stack: {
                children: [
                  {
                    component: {
                      id: 'List',
                      name: 'List'
                    }
                  }
                ],
                options: {
                  bottomTab: {
                    testID: 'buttonTab1',
                    icon: sources[0]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              stack: {
                children: [
                  {
                    component: {
                      name: 'Noti',
                      id: 'Noti'
                    }
                  }
                ],
                options: {
                  bottomTab: {
                    testID: 'buttonTab2',
                    icon: sources[1]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    });
  });
};
```

I'm able to make visible false the actual bottomtab once i've changed the page but i'm not able to replace for a new one or get the workaround to make this possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to exactly solve your problem, but I wanted to hide the tab bar in my case on a few screens. I think you could do the same, hide the tabBar wherever needed and render your own custom tab by nesting a tabNavigator inside the main Navigator.

Refer to [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5376) for hiding the TabBar

Comment: Thanks divye but i'm using react native navigation not react navigation, but i think i'll give it a shot.